# Need advice on how to fix RBLPopover so that it will dynamically resize like NSPopover

Tags: macos, cocoa, github, nspopover

RBLPopover is a Popover made by the Guys from Github that aims to mimimc NSPopover but fixes some of it's flaws, like canBecomeKeyWindow. It is part of the Rebel Framework they currently hosting on GitHub. I decided to use this Popover for my Statusbar Application and ran now into a problem. NSPopover is able to resize it's size dynamically and animated if it's shown and you use setContentSize. Then it will automatically resize animated to the newly given size. However, RBLPopover is not doing that. After 8 hours on looking into RBLPopover's Code I was not able to fix this, one reason will be lag of knowledge on my Part on how Views work internally in Detail.

The Code for RBLPopover can be found here:

https://github.com/github/Rebel/blob/master/Rebel/RBLPopover.m

Can someone give me a hint on how to fix this? I don't ask for code, just some advice/concept on how to achieve this. Is there some Method that is missing in it's parent class? I don't believe that showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge: is the right method to change. I believe that something more fundamental is missing but I don't get it.